# I'm trying to utilize Click Funnels, and inject into the "Header Custom Tracking" some JS, but its loading after the Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect someone that is outside of the United States, but the Page loads before the script does and it looks tacky. Obviously I'm not able to hide the body or anything like that, I'm not certain if the issue lies with the redirect itself waiting for the page to load, or if it is because the html keeps loading, which I didn't think was a thing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var QueryString = function () {

  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
  return query_string;
}();


  $.getJSON( "https://freegeoip.net/json/", function( data ) {
    if(data.country_name = "United States")
    {

        window.location.replace("https://my.draxe.com/hlg-success-intl" + '?' + 'inf_field_Email=' + QueryString.inf_field_Email);
        //window.location.href = "https://my.draxe.com/hlg-success-intl";
    }
  });
  </script>
```

I'm attempting to redirect someone that is outside of the United States, but the Page loads before the script does and it looks tacky. Obviously I'm not able to hide the body or anything like that, I'm not certain if the issue lies with the redirect itself waiting for the page to load, or if it is because the html keeps loading, which I didn't think was a thing.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but no I don't believe I ever got anywhere with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clickfunnels is kind of weird with how it handles it's custom html/javascript.

If you look at the page source, you'll see that your code is not injected into the dom as the page is created on the server, it's stored inside another element and then click funnel's JS code injects it into the dom.  This makes it impossible to run your code before theirs(I assume this is why they do it this way).

So, basically, there is no way to do what you're asking.  At least as far as we've been able to figure out, and we're pretty deep in their code(currently looking at trying to hijack their form submissions to inject custom variables into the redirect url... I wouldn't advise it)

Comment: It seems that I can see the code when looking in page source code in it was put in Header section of Tracking code in CF